# How to use JQuery Selector in PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-selectors

May be be it's simple but I am unable to find a solution, being a NewBie to selectors:

Here is my HTML:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="BookmarksPopup">
    <ol id=listBookmarksPopup data-role=listview data-inset=false data-theme="e">
        <li><a name="APopupOption3" data-icon="home" onclick="SaveBookmark()">Bookmark this Audio</a></li>
        <li><a name="APopupOption4" data-icon="home" onclick="SaveBookmarkPage()">Bookmark this Page</a></li>
        <li><a name="APopupOption5" data-icon="home" onclick="DeleteBookmarks()">Delete Bookmarks</a></li>
        <li><a name="APopupOption6" data-icon="home" onclick="displayMenu()">My Bookmarks</a></li>
    </ol>
</div><!-- /popup BookmarkPopup-->
```

In JavScript I want to perform some function based on the "name" attribute. Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ol > li").click(function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('name') );
  });
});
```

but alert( $(this).attr('name') ) returns "undefined". Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DOM structure given by you, the `LI tag` does not have any attribute named 'name'. I am saying this because your `$(this)` object will points to the `Li tag` which is being clicked currently, So in order to get the attribute of the `anchor tag` inside it, you should use `.find()` to select it, which is the descendant of the clicked `LI tag`. Please read here to know more about [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ol > li").click(function(){
    alert( $(this).find('a').attr('name') );
  });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dTCmu/)

Or if you want to select those `anchor` tag and bind `click` with it,

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ol > li a").click(function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('name') );
  });
});
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/dTCmu/1/)